# Adding external dependency (FLANN) to catkin package

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to add [FLANN](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) (Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors) as a system dependency to a catkin package. I installed FLANN from the source as instructed on the website and then setup my ROS package's CMakeList.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(nao_whole_body_ik)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp)
    
find_package( PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules( flann REQUIRED flann )
    
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES nao_whole_body_ik
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(test_node src/test1_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Then in my `test1_node.cpp` file I just have the test code given on their website, which consists of the following 2 include directives:

```
#include <flann/flann.hpp>
#include <flann/io/hdf5.h>
```

The first include statement works fine. The second one produces a long list of linking errors complaining about undefined references to various functions. I'm not very good at configuring the CMakeLists file, but I suspect that I need to add `hdf5` as a system dependency as well, but I can't figure out how to add multiple system dependencies. Simply writing `pkg_check_modules( flann REQUIRED flann hdf5 )` doesn't work.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224540/adding-external-dependency-(flann)-to-catkin-package/) by [Ali250](https://answers.ros.org/users/24947/ali250/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the problem by simply adding this line to `CMakeLists.txt` above `find_package`:

```
FIND_LIBRARY(HDF5_LIBRARY hdf5 /usr/local/hdf5/lib/)
```

and then after creating the executable:

```
target_link_libraries(test_node ${CATKIN_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARY}})
```

Also, it's better to install hdf5 by compiling the source code. Initially I tried doing it from the repository but it said that the library was already installed even though it wasn't.

---

Originally posted by [Ali250](https://answers.ros.org/users/24947/ali250/) with karma: 41 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1